# Installing new patch in magento

Tags: magento, patch

I have this patch in Magento which is `patch.sh` and I want to run this file and execute it. I logged in and tried to install using SSH way. I'm using PUTTY. When I run the `patch.sh` file I encountered an error, and I don't know how  to fix it. Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 44.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 62.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 73.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 541.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 55.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 143.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 160.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 2834.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej
```

How should I fix it or where should I start to debug the problem?

Comment: Easy thing to check first - you're *sure* you have the right patch for your version of Magento? I've, er, a friend once...  did exactly that mistake and saw something like this before.

Comment: ok i will try to check the right patch and install a new one

Comment: i use the right version of my magento.. still in errors :(

Comment: Have you modified any of those core files to change functionality?

Comment: hmmm if that modified those cored files does it affect functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

Either your Magento installation is already patched, or you have modifications in core files (*app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php* for example and so on).
The solution is to compare your current files with original files from Magento distribution and understand why your files got changed.
If you believe there should be no any changes in core files, you can simply replace *app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php*, *app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php* and so on with original files from corresponding Magento distribution and re-run the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Try on your /var/www magento root

```
rm -rf var/cache var/session
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
```